# NoMethodError simple_form_for in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form-for

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%=f.text_field :title%>
  <%= f.label :phone %>
  <%=f.text_field :phone%>
  <%= f.label :description %>
  <%=f.text_field :description%>
  <%= f.submit%>
<% end %>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MBzz.png)
how i can solve this

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've done the following:

- Added `simple_form` to your `Gemfile`
- Run `bundle install`
- Restarted your rails server

Then attempt this action again.